# Problems with ref in components (Vue)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a parent component in which I want to use a specific child component multiple times. The child component contains an input field with a two-way data binding like this:

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
    <div style="overflow-y: auto;" class="dialog" data-role="dialog" id="keypadDialog">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input v-model="numberKey" class="mt-2" style="font-size:20px; text-align:center; width:90%; height: 60px" readonly />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button outline" @click="setVal('1')">1</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('2')">2</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('3')">3</button>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: center">
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('4')">4</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('5')">5</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('6')">6</button>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('7')">7</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('8')">8</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('9')">9</button>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: center">
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('A')">A</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('0')">0</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('S')">S</button>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="setVal('/')">/</button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button  outline" @click="clearSingle()"><span class="mif-arrow-left"></span></button>
            <button style="width:90px; height:90px;" class="button outline" @click="clearAll()"><span class="mif-cross-light mt-2"></span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="dialog-actions">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <button style="height: 60px; width:80%" class="button dark outline mt-2" @click="closeKeypad()">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="showKeypad">
        <input @click="openKeypad()" type="text" data-role="input" v-model="numberKey" data-search-button="true" readonly>
    </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, ref, unref } from 'vue';
    import Metro from 'metro4';
    import TabellenKomponente from '../Components/TabellenKomponente.vue'

    export default defineComponent({
        emits: ['sendSelectedVal'],
        components: { TabellenKomponente },
        props: {
            showKeypad: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
        },
        setup() {
            return {
                filterStat: true,
                numberKey: ref(""),
                value: ref(""),
                counter: 0,
            }
        },
        updated() {

            if (this.showKeypad && this.counter == 0) {
                this.counter++;
            }
        },

        methods: {
            openKeypad() {
                Metro.init();
                Metro.dialog.open('#keypadDialog')
            },

            setVal(val) {
                this.numberKey = `${this.numberKey}${val}`
            },

            clearSingle() {
                this.numberKey = this.numberKey.slice(0, -1);
            },

            clearAll() {
                this.numberKey = "";
            },

            closeKeypad() {
                this.value = unref(this.numberKey)
                Metro.init();
                Metro.dialog.close('#keypadDialog')
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

The variable `numberKey` is declared as a `ref()` in the setup() method of my child component.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <TestRefError :showKeypad="shKeyPad"></TestRefError>
    <TestRefError :showKeypad="shKeyPad"></TestRefError>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
    import TestRefError from '../Components/TestReferror.vue'
    import Metro from 'metro4';

    export default defineComponent({
        components: { TestRefError},

        setup() {
            Metro.init()
            return {
                shKeyPad:true,
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

In my parent component I have the problem that if I am using these child components multiple times one component access the instance of the other component.
[image]

In other words if I am changing/setting the value in the second child component the value in the first child component gets changed as well.
So in the picture this means if I am using the second input field the value gets set in the first one.

Unfortunately I could not find something with which I could solve this problem but I think this is not something new so I apologize if this is a duplicate. I thought I could use `reactive()`
because I think it does a "deeper copy" but this also result in the same problem. I hope I explained my problem understandable. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** As in the code example displayed I tried to use`unref()` but this also did not work

**EDIT2** As mentioned in the comment section I looked up v-model. The problem is I try to build a Keypad. For this Keypad ( displayed in my code example) I have to assign the corresponding value by pressing a button. To resolve the issue I do this without a ref (as mentioned in the comment section) but in this case I can not assign a value to the modelValue. So how can I assign the values of the button without using a ref ?

Comment: Please share code of the components. It is hard to tell by just the HTML template what the issue is.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Excuse me hopfully my edit will make things clearer.

Comment: If you want to use separate values, just don't use ref. You can use [emit](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to fire custom events if you want to catch value changes in the parent.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Ok, but in this case  how would I update the value in the input field from my keypad dialog without using the ref?

Comment: Why not use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) to pass data between child and parent?

Comment: @PeterKrebs I do use v-model but the problem is that the value does not update if I only use v-moldel I do also have to combine it with a ref otherwise the value would not change in the input field. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Both the input field and the function to change it´s values are in the child component. The parent only uses the component

Comment: No you have to pass the v-model through the parent, see v-model link from my comment above. The parent has to have a variable for each of the models. Please post your attempt with v-model as well.